# vcpkg: `pwsh.exe` is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio, vcpkg

I am a user of [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) C++ libraries manager on Windows 11, and recently I updated `vcpkg` to the latest tagged version `2024.01.12` (after removing an older version) using the commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
git checkout 2024.01.12
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg integrate install
```

And now in Visual Studio 2022, during building of my existing projects or even after creation of new Console App project, I get the error in Build Output windows:

```
1>'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
1>operable program or batch file.
```

But the build continues and succeeds.

Does it mean that the error is not important and safe to ignore? And even if so, what was wrong in the installation process or how can I silence this error?